# Cannot interact with drive D

Tags: windows

I have problems working with drive `D`. When I create a new folder, there is a message `You need to confirm this operation`. I choose `Continue`, the folder will still be created. But I can't save any files in drive `D`, with the message `You don't have permission to save in this location`. I think I may have mistakenly deleted some important files in this drive before. How can I handle this situation?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have a backup of the data on that volume. Then delete the volume in the Disk Management console and recreate it. This will reset the permissions to the default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick answer: you have somehow damaged the file permissions for your D: drive, possibly setting the permission for Everyone to Deny Write, or changing ownership to Administrators (e.g.) or some other user than yourself.

To avoid doing this in the future don't make changes in permissions that you are not certain of. If you don't know how to work with permissions (it's right-click on the disk or folder, select Properties and the Security tab), ask again in Superuser.

It can be very difficult to repair broken/wrong permissions on an entire drive. As joequerty mentions in their comment: You should probably simply backup this drive, then delete and recreate the entire volume in Disk Management.

Comment: I will add something about Bitlocker, because the locker icon. Please OP check if you don't have any configuration about bitlocker on this drive.

Comment: @FuxT - That’s EFS not BitLocker blocking the author

Comment: Yep, i watched it twice and that's obviously the problem